# Reading a DXF file in R with readOGR

Tags: r, rgdal, dxf

I want to read a DXF in R using RGDAL package. DXF is supported by RGDAL, but I am not able to read the file and I don't find information about this topic. With shapefiles I do not have any problems.

Here is my source-code:

```
library(rgdal)
library("rgeos")
library(RPostgreSQL)
my.layer <- readOGR(dsn = "./IN/Gear Sample-iss4.DXF", layer = "0")
```

Output:

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding,
>   use_iconv = use_iconv,  :    Cannot open layer

Comment: Try setting your directory path via "dsn = " and your layer name separately via "layer = ". This is the default behaviour for shapefiles. In your example you have a whitespace in your directory path in combination with the file name, which will cause trouble. Note also that the `readOGR` documentation states: "interpretation varies by driver — for some drivers, dsn is a file name, but may also be a folder". This means, that the procedure for shapefiles MAY not work for .dxf files.

Comment: The space in the name is not the problem. I have found that the entire contents of the .dwg file is represented as a single layer named "entities". ` my.layer <- readOGR(dsn ="./IN/GearSampleiss4.DXF", layer ="entities")`

Comment: More info: http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward: there is no layer named "0" in the file. For DXF, the layer name is set in the file... It would seem like yours uses a different name than the default "0".

Try listing the layers to confirm the name:

```
ogrListLayers("./IN/Gear Sample-iss4.DXF")
```